# Ubuntu 22.04 VirtualBox client, the copy and paste between host and client stops working

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, copy-and-paste

Ubuntu 22.04 VirtualBox client. 
 After upgrading  the kernel from 5.15.0-39-generic to 5.15.0-40-generic, the copy and paste between host and client stopped working.

Anybody else has the same problem and how to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: You may have to update "Guest Additions" in your guest